# TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is part of code

```python3
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # The command /patch return a link with the latest patch note
    if message.content.startswith('/patch'):
        await message.channel.send(message.channel, 'Last patchnotes: https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en/news')
    # The command /rank return attribute a rank according to the K/D of the user
```

used discord.py

when you type /patch

here's what the console shows

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FeNka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 107, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(message.channel, 'Last patchnotes: https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en/news')
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: you probably don't need to send `message.channel` as that's an attribute in `self` for the `message` class

Answer (score 1):

Your call should be changed to

```
await message.channel.send('Last patchnotes: https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en/news')
```

`send` is a function of the `message.channel` class, and thus has access to `self`. Its call probably looks something like:

```
def send(self, message):
    #does things
```

`self` is implicit here, you don't send it, and that's why it looks like `2` args were passed when `3` actually were sent